# Right-align TOC title using KOMA or tocloft for the scrreprt class

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, alignment

I seriously hope this question hasn't been asked before, but I couldn't find one that fits my exact case.

I'm using the `scrreprt` document class and successfully right-aligned the chapter titles using:

```
\renewcommand{\raggedchapter}{\raggedleft}
```

This also worked for the title of the list of listings. However, it did **not** work for the titles of the TOC, the list of figures and the list of tables. I tried some things like:

```
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\raggedleft}
```

but this did not right-align the title, but instead just reset the font-size (which is to be expected for a renew).

There's probably some easy way of doing this using either KOMA or tocloft, but I couldn't find anything that worked so far. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The KOMA classes are not fond of the `tocloft` package and will make a bunch of suggestions which, as a non-user of KOMA, mean nothing to me. However the following short MWE shows how to use `tocloft` to get the ToC, etc., titles right aligned.

```
% toctitleprob.tex  SE 563186

\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\raggedchapter}{\raggedleft}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\LARGE\bfseries\sffamily}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A chapter}

\end{document}
```

Perhaps you can translate this into `scrreprt` code.

Comment: Thanks so much! This actually did the trick! I'm not a KOMA user myself, but I got a scrreprt based template for my thesis, that I wanted to adapt a little.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: Do not use package `tocloft` together with a KOMA-Script class. It breaks several KOMA-Script features. KOMA-Script uses its own package `tocbasic` for the ToC and lists like LoF and LoT.

If you really want to use package `tocloft` and `tocloft` should not change the settings of the headings in TOC etc. you can load it with option `titles`.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}% I would not use this package with a KOMA-Script class

\renewcommand{\raggedchapter}{\raggedleft}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A chapter}
\end{document}
```